# Can't access CSS properties in my unit tests

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I've been trying to run unit tests to check some CSS properties in my Angular 4+ app but their values are always empty. Here's my test:

```
it('should have a background a color', () => {
  const toolbar = debug.query(By.css('.toolbar'));
  const toolbarEl = toolbar.nativeElement;
  expect(toolbarEl.style.background).toBeTruthy();
});
```

**Failure:** `Expected '' to be truthy.`

**console.log:** empty string.

In my component's CSS (toolbar.component.scss), I have the following class:

```
.toolbar {
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
}
```

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: The  `style` property only reads/writes inline styles.

Comment: Is there an alternative for testing without inline styles?

Comment: You are lucky there is one: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle `window.getComputedStyle(toolbarEl).backgroundColor` should do the trick

Comment: I see. However, that will always give a value - even if the stylesheet doesn't set a property. In that case, the test will always pass.

Comment: And, according to [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/testing#the-first-asynchronous-beforeeach) calling `compileComponents()` should compile both the template and the css: `When compileComponents completes, the external templates and css files have been "inlined" and TestBed.createComponent can create new instances of BannerComponent synchronously.`

Comment: Test should be as specific as possible and never contain loose assertions. If it's `blue`, don't assert it to be truthy.

Comment: That's a fair point.

Comment: @WillHalpert I know this issue is years old, but adding this for future readers: Every HTML element has almost all attributes filled with values. Even if you don't assign any value, the browser will natively add default values. So there is no case where a color, backgroundcolor, width etc will be "null" or "undefined". Even a blank "<body>" has a background-color, size etc. So make sure that you understand this and test for specific values :)